# network flooding

Tags: networking

i have been reading about network flooding algorithm that it is used to discover new nodes and then the "addresses" are added into the hash table of a switch. Now what if a frame is send in all the networks nodes, but some of the nodes that are in the network are not programmed to receive data, but just to send data. how are those added on any of the hash tables on the switch(es)  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are not programmed to receive data, then they wouldn't receive it I guess.  Someone might have to manually program the data into the "router".  However I *doubt* the **likely-hood** of a router or switch being unable to receive data, that would seem entirely pointless.